# Mute in OS X Mail

Tags: mail.app

Gmail offers a feature called “mute” that silently archives future email that arrives in a thread. It makes reply-all threads way nicer to work with.

Is there an add-on or something that enables this behaviour in Mail?

Comment: Any news in this thread?

Answer (score 7):

This can be done in stock Mail.app, but it takes a few steps.

First, go to **Mail** » **Preferences…** and in the **General** tab, set **New messages sound:** to *None*.

[image]

Then, click the **Rules** tab.

Create a new rule.

Under description, type `Sound`.

Set the rule to apply if *all* conditions are met.

For any thread you do not want to sound the new messages sound, enter the content of its subject line (not the Fwd: or Re: parts) in the field for *Subject* then *does not contain*.

For the **action**, set *Play Sound* to *New Messages Sound*.

[image]

Whenever you want to add a thread to the exclusion list, add a condition.

If you frequently add threads to this list, this process can be scripted -- but writing that script would be another question (which you're welcome to post if you want to go this route).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Daniel, but I'm not as concerned with the audible sound the messages make when they arrive in a particular thread but that I just don’t see new messages in a muted thread appear.

Comment: @EdwardOcampo-Gooding Do you want them to be marked as read? If so, same procedure, but change the payload – instead of *all*, say *any*; instead of *Does not contain* say *contains*; instead of *Play Sound* say *Mark as read*.

Comment: Yep, that’s what I’m after. Is there a hotkey I can hit from the regular mode to add the current subject to a rule? Where should I look if I need to script this kind of action?

Comment: You could post a question on this site asking for such a script :-)

Comment: (I'm working on writing such a script; if you post a question asking for an AppleScript to mark all future messages bearing a particular subject line as read, I hope to be able to post an answer to it)

Answer (score 7):

I'll give the correct but non-answer: **No it's not possible.**

Gmail's mute feature is proprietary to Gmail. Even if Apple decided they wanted to add the ability to use the feature, I don't think Gmail exposes it over IMAP anyway.